# How to deal with null values using Python format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to essentially strip out the extra period if a value is null or None. If `myvar` doesn't exist, it should print `abc.xyz`

```
myvar="def"
print "abc.{0}.xyz".format(myvar)
abc.def.xyz

myvar=""
print "abc.{0}.xyz".format(myvar)
abc..xyz
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if `myvar` is `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a character is present in the original string it will be included regardless after calling format for it.  What needs to be done is to modify the input such that it will include whatever extra character when the intended value is present.  Consider the following (encapsulated in a function as a demo):

```
def demo(value):
    print("abc.{0}xyz".format(value + '.' if value else ''))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> demo('def')
abc.def.xyz
>>> demo('')
abc.xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the period to myvar.

```
myvar = (myvar + '.') if myvar else myvar
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
>>> myvar=""
>>> print "abc.{0}.xyz".format(myvar) if myvar else "abc.xyz"
abc.xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all instances of double periods with just one.

```
myvar=""
output = "abc.{0}.xyz".format(myvar)
print str.replace(output, "..", ".")
abc.xyz
```